# React Native Sound Not Working (Remote URL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

class RemoteSound extends Component {

  playTrack = () => { 
    
    const track = new Sound('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3', null, (e) => {
      if (e) {
        alert('error loading track:', e)
      } else {
        track.play()
      }
    })

  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="play me" onPress={()=>{
      this.playTrack();
    }} />
  }
}

export default RemoteSound
```

Problem : when I add this line "**import Sound from 'react-native-sound'**" ,
I got this error  : **Cannot read property 'IsAndroid' of undefined
Evaluating react-native-sound.js**

and remote url not playing.

Question 1 : this library  not used any  more  **react-native-sound**

Question 2 : do you have current example in react native . In many websites , I tried many example but all of them is not working.

Comment: Did the answer helped solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the repo home page:

> If you encounter this error
>
> ```
> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid')
> ```
>
> know that this is the most common build issue. See [#592](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/592) and the
> several issues linked from it for possible resolution. A pull request
> with improved documentation on this would be welcome!

Depending on your environment (operating system, docker, etc) the solution may vary. Please, visit that issue [#592](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/592) for more details, or add relevant info to the question.